# CRM 2016 web apis with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

We have CRM 2016 on premise and  want to consume the API using c# :

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() {Credentials = credentials});
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxx.elluciancrmrecruit.com/api/data/v8.0/datatel_events");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("datatel_events?$orderby=datatel_eventname").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   var yourcustomobjects = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else
{
   //Something has gone wrong, handle it here
}
```

But it always return HTML page says try later instead of the json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query the OData endpoint to get the information you are looking for assuming `date1_events` is a custom entity (although the naming convention seems to be off).

As an example to query `contacts`:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() {Credentials = credentials})
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxx.elluciancrmrecruit.com/api/data/v8.0/")
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = client.GetAsync("accounts?$top=1").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var yourcustomobjects = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. II tried to use your code and now it says 401 unauthorized access. I'm using same username and password to login to CRM . Any suggestions

Comment: Is your user name correctly formatted(including domain name)? Try passing the domain name via the `NetWorkCredential` overload?

Comment: I did add domain and it is authenticating fine but I get this message 

Error
An error has occurred. 

Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics CRM Administrator. Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support.

Comment: Couple of things, are you sure the entity name is "datatel_event"? Secondly, this line already ends with the entity set `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxx.elluciancrmrecruit.com/api/data/v8.0/datatel_events");` , change it to `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxx.elluciancrmrecruit.com/api/data/v8.0/");`

Comment: yes i'm sure and I tried to test with  accounts?$top=1.
I already changed it but still not working

Comment: I would also try appending organization name like so: `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxx.elluciancrmrecruit.com/ORGXXX/api/data/v8.0/")`